# Chromium wants to download a html page

Tags: nginx, wordpress, php-fpm

An issue that happens much too often, but this time I can't find the way out:

I have a Wordpress site using the following special permalink configuration: `/%post_id%/%postname%/`. Everything seems to work but I have just one issue with Chromium:

Assume the following URL: http://example.com/123/the-title-of-the-post/

**When I open it in Firefox everything's fine. When I open it in Chromium, it shows a save-as-window.**

The same post is also available under http://example.com/123/. When I use this URL everything's fine in Firefox and also Chromium shows the blog post.

Ok. So I thought it might be a Content-Type issue, but, the output for `curl -D - -o /dev/null <URL>` looks the same for both URLs from above. Both outputs contain the line `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

The website is running on nginx but it does not contain a special configuration for permalink-URLs.

Now I am a little bit lost, because I don't know which part of the system causes this issue. Is it **Chromium**? Is it **Nginx**? Is it **PHP5-FPM**? Or is it **Wordpress** itself? Any idea?

Comment: [This probably will need the actual URL](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) to resolve it, so that people can see it for themselves.

Comment: maybe one thing: everything is up to date. even wordpress is at version 3.9.1.

Comment: Can you check for the headers sent to chrome via its dev tools?  Something might be different based on user agent or cookies that you won't see in `curl`.

Comment: Oh no!! Thanks you for this hint. Even when using Ctrl+F5 Chromium loaded the site from cache. Now I purged the cache for all websites and it works...

Answer (score 0):

Too bad. It was just a caching issue and I had to write this question to find it out.

Purging the cache in Chromium helped.